# Making child element have same width and border as parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, list

For example I have a "li" tag that inside it there is an "a" tag. I want the whole row to have a border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;

```
<li class=sub">
     <a href="3" class="active">
         <span id="1">Text</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

Currently I have

```
span {
    width: 90%;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
    font-size:12px;
}

li {
    width: 100%;
}
```

But it seems that only the Text will get underlined, i would want the whole "li" which takes like a whole row to be underlined. But not underlining the "li" but the "span" tag. So basically would want my "span" tag to be same width as parent "li" not sure what i am missing on my CSS.

Comment: Span is a inline element. If you want to set a width on the span, you can add `display:inline-block` for your span in your css.

Comment: a {display:block;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}, no span needed i guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must understand that `span` **is an inline element**, and for such there is no such thing as `width`, to make the `span` inherit a width, you need to make sure that you set the `display` to a `block`element, in your case, try `inline-block`.

live example: http://jsbin.com/liwah/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: good catch everyone! Its part of something larger but helps understand what I was doing wrong. thx